# Routing in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, url-routing

I am currently express router in Node.js and having a problem like below. Let's say I have two url; one is to get a user info and one is to register users to an application.

> http://example.com/users/:idUser (this will give a information of a user)
>
> http://example.com/users/registration (this will allow a user registration)

The problem I have facing is when I call registration, the router is working with `idUser`; so I had to edit like `user/registration` instead of `users`. If I want to use as `users/registration`, which kinds of work do I have to do. I am still a newbie in Node.js.

Thanks.

Comment: You can order your routes so that `/users/registration` gets processed first and it should match before `/users/:idUser` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to order the routes appropriately so that the registration route comes before.

```
app.get('/users/registration', function(req, res, next) {
    ....
});

app.get('/users/:userId', function(req, res, next) {
   ....
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I just realised how dump I am :)

Comment: Lol. It's a common mistake. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Just invert the order, like this:

```
app.get('/users/registration', function(req, res, next) {
    ...
});
app.get('/users/:userId', function(req, res, next) {
    ...
});
```